# SVN repository path aliases

Tags: svn, alias

Is there a way to alias svn paths?  I'm tired of writing

```
svn *command* svn+ssh://dev.myserver.com/var/svn/myproject
```

every time I need to checkout, switch, or tag.  Is there a way I can alias the repository path, so I can just run:

```
svn *command* myserver/myproject
```

My poor ol' fingers are tired :(

Comment: Solution is slightly OS-dependent. You have to implement it by hand, anyway. Hint - url of repo can be extracted from `svn info` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias in your .bashrc file:

```
alias sitesvn="svn info | egrep '^URL: (.*)' | sed s/URL\:\ //"
```

to be tested on all possible protocols and modified, if needed. If current form this alias can be used as `svn *command* $(sitesvn)`
(sitesvn is full RepoURL for used WC)

Comment: Thanks!  Now.. if only my svn repo wasn't out of space .. :)